# JavaScript function that alternates YouTube embed sources? (No iframe)

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, src, alternate

The intention is upon clicking a button for the YouTube video embed code (without iframe) to generate another YouTube video embed code - here is my HTML:

```
<p><button onClick="philscode()">Click Here!</button></p>
+

<div id="video0"><embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/dP_ZPEMrJxY" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200px" height="140px" allowfullscreen="true"></div>
```

I basically need the embedded YouTube video (above) to be replaced by another YouTube video. I don't want to have to use jQuery either. Here is the JavaScript I have currently:

```
<script>


    var embedcodes = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vxq6K6yLm0"];


    function philscode() 
    {document.getElementById("video0").innerHTML = embedcodes [0];

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a demo http://embed.plnkr.co/phmNaQD2JQa4RH8ITK0I

```
 <script>
        var embedcodes = ["http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"];
        function philscode()
        {
            var el =   document.getElementById("video0Embed");
            var clone=el.cloneNode(true);
            clone.setAttribute('src', embedcodes [0]);
            el .parentNode.replaceChild(clone,el );
        }
    </script>
    <p><button onClick="philscode()">Click Here!</button></p>
    <div id="video0">
        <embed width="420" height="315" id="video0Embed"
               src="https://www.youtube.com/v/dP_ZPEMrJxY">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I receive a syntax error on the "var el = part". I don't know where I place the src so that the div id="video0" is replaced by another id.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you. Is it possible if you could tell me how to make changes to the function code if I want to insert more than one YouTube embed code?